# Java - Delaying an event without a Thread/Timer

Tags: java, events, arraylist, delay, frame-rate

In the later levels of my game alot of zombies are spawned at the same time (up to 200) so the fps will be lowered because of all the zombies on screen, therefor I want to make it so that one zombie is spawned every second to reduce some of the lag but I don't want to use a Thread/Timer to accomplish this because by using that Thread/Timer it would reduce the fps and I don't want to reduce the fps when I'm trying to make it higher. How could I accomplish this (I use an ArrayList to spawn the zombies)?

Comment: GUI library? Swing? How would you propose doing such a thing without threads/timer/ScheduledExecutorService? I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you spawn a zombie, store the current time (in milliseconds). During the game loop, check the difference between the current time and the stored time to determine if you need to spawn a zombie, if so, update this as the new current time.

Comment: yep, reply on the time difference as shown by the system time, and not based on the speed of the Timer or game loop. 1+